# Как использовать attr_accessible в Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как использовать attr_accessible (может есть аналог) в Rails 5? Гем protected_attributes не работает, так как есть конфликт с версиями activemodel и activerecord. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный атрибут не работает в современных версиях фреймворка Ruby on Rails. Ранее он использовался для того, чтобы на уроне модели явно задать атрибуты, которые можно будет "массово" редактировать на уровне контроллера (т.е. в группе параметров, которые поступают из формы). Данная практика признана неудачной, во-первых вы неявно разрешаете возможность редактирования для всех контроллеров, которых может быть много (как минимум приложение и система администрирования), во-вторых вы на уровне модели явно выдаете разрешения, которые должны выдаваться в уровне контроллера. В третьих слишком вольное использование этого атрибута (и для backend и для frontend частей приложения) приводило к уязвимостям приложений, когда с frontend-части можно было путем манипуляций содержимым POST-содержимого менять те параметры модели, которые не разрешено менять с frontend-части, но которые были разрешены в `attr_accessible` например для backend-части сайта.

Начиная с версии Ruby on Rails 4, для разрешение присвоения параметров текущей модели было перемещено с уровня моделей на уровень контроллера. Теперь вам нужно явно указать какие параметры разрешено изменять в модели на уровне контроллера. Например, один из возможных вариантов может выглядеть так

```
class SomeController < Admin::ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    resource = Resourse.new
    resource.assign_attributes(resoure_params)
    if resource.save
      redirect_to index_page
    else
      render resource.new_record? ? :new : :edit
    end
  end
  ...
  private

  def resourse_params
    [ :id, :name, :weight ]
  end
  ...
end
```

или можно явно пройтись по параметрам, отметить при помощи метода `permit` те, которые можно передавать модели и воспользоваться например методом `create`

```
class SomeController < Admin::ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    if Resourse.create resource_params
      redirect_to index_page
    else
      render resource.new_record? ? :new : :edit
    end
  end
  ...
  private

  def resource_params
    params.require(:resource).permit(:id, :name, :weight)
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Спасибо, за полный, полезный и развёрнутый ответ)